# How to compare strings for 3/4 matches

Tags: ruby, string, comparison

Need to compare numbers in an array to 'winning' number. But I have to see if 3 out of 4 match. eg "1234" is my number and winning=["4356","8312","4820","7623"] . In this case "8312" should alert a win because they have 1 2&3 in common. I have to define the numbers in a unit test, then write a function in a separate file then pass that function back into the unit test. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I already wrote a function and test comparing for an exact match and dont have any idea on what next step to take.

function_file

```
 def match(my_num,arr)
  matches = []
  arr.each_with_index do |v,i|
     if my_num == v
        matches << my_num
     end
   end
  matches
end
```

test_file

```
require "minitest/autorun"
require_relative "close_but_no_func.rb"

class TestWinningNumbers < Minitest::Test
    def test_1_equals_1
        assert_equal(10-5, 3+2)
    end
    def test_winning_num
        my_num = "1134"
        arr=["6028","2088","3058","3476","8740","1134"]
        assert_equal(["1134"], match(my_num, arr))
    end     
end
```

Comment: Should `"1111"` cause a match?

Comment: And do the positions matter? So does `"1234"` match `"4321"`?

Comment: Also I don't think your `match` function does what you are hoping it does.

Comment: @adrian Sauls I tried to answer, but the functions I put might still be wrong for what you want, as you did not give clear indications how multiple occurances are to be handled.

Comment: @adrian I really recommend to try some exercises on http://exercism.io/languages/ruby/about learned a lot about these kinds of problems over there.

Comment: "1111" would not match, and positions do not matter. Thank you all again. Roland, I think your answer covers it perfectly.

Comment: @AdrianSauls If my answer works for you, then it is common practice to accept that answer, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So let us divide this problem into two seperate problems.

1. You want a function that counts the number of matching characters.
2. Then you want to collect these strings together, if they have enough matching characters.

You could for example write a function that checks how many characters of the both strings match.

```
def count_matching_chars(str1,str2)
  # counts how many characters of str1 appear in str2
  matching_chars_count = 0
  str1.each_char do |char| 
    matching_chars_count += 1 if str2.include?(char)
  end
  matching_chars_count
end

puts count_matching_chars("1234", "1134") => 3
puts count_matching_chars("1111", "1134") => 4
puts count_matching_chars("1234", "1111") => 1
```

This one here ignores the positioning, it just checks, how many of the characters of `str1` match one character of `str2`.

Now you can easily collect these numbers in an array.

```
def matches(my_num, arr)
  result = []
  arr.each do |num|
    result << arr if count_matching_chars(my_num,num) >= 3
  end
  result
end
```

You can write both functions in a more compact way, by using enumerator functions like `count` and `select`:

```
def count_matching_chars(str1,str2)
  str1.each_char.count do |char| 
    str2.include?(char)
  end
end

def matches(my_num, arr)
  arr.select do |num|
    return true if count_matching_chars(num,my_num) >= 3
  end
end
```

Or you then combine everything into one function

```
def matches(my_num, arr)
  arr.select do |num|
    true if my_num.each_char.count { |char| num.include?(char)} >= 3
  end
end
```

Now if you just want to check, if it is a winning number. You just return `true` as soon as you find a match:

```
def winning_number?(my_num, arr)
  arr.select do |num|
    return true if my_num.each_char.count { |char| num.include?(char)} >= 3
  end
end
```